# How does module.exports object work without keys?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

How does `module.exports` work for an object without keys? For example, if I have in `test.js`

```
const two = 2;
const three = 3;
module.exports = {two, three};    // Is the right-hand side an object? If so, where are its keys?
                                  // It doesn't look like it's object destructuring.
```

and in `app.js`

```
const test = require("./test");
console.log(test.two);            // 2
console.log(test.three);          // 3
```

Comment: It's not anything specific to `module.exports` - that's just the shorthand for object creation introduced in ES6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
module.exports = {two, three};
```

is a shorthand notation for:

```
module.exports = {two: two, three: three};
```

Both generate the exact same object.  This has nothing specially to do with `module.exports`.  It's just an [ES6 object initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) shorthand way of declaring an object where you want the property name to be the same as your variable name.